# How Can I resolve this Error Message from Tortoise Git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Today I committed a change to my Develop branch and when going to push the changes, I received this error. Does anyone have any experience with this?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot provides context, but pasting just the error (and not the awesome ASCII art) as text would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by the error message (below ASCII art),

> Branch refs/heads/DEVELOP can only be modified through pull requests.

You'd have to create a branch from `DEVELOP`, then put your changes on it (through cherry-pick, arguably) then push it to remote and *then* create a pull request from your new branch to `DEVELOP`.